# Magento URL Rewrite by Overriding Model

Tags: magento

Is there a Base model which I can rewrite my URLs by overriding that model.

I have Lots of URLs and I need to use redirect them without adding them to **category URL rewrite Management**

I can do this by overriding **Mage_Core_Model_App** but unfortunately Magento not allowed to override App model.

Example:
Old URLS : [www.old.com/pro/1232](http://www.old.com/pro/1232)

New Url: [www.mage.com/my-product.html](http://www.mage.com/my-product.html)

I wanted to redirect Old URL to new URL without using URL rewrite Management in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

We've done a similar thing using Apache rewrites.

You should be able to configure the rewrites in whatever web server you use.